# define width of ng-model textarea

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm creating a contact page for my website, and I'm using Angular for display the text of the user.
Anyway, I want to define a width for the `textarea` - when the user crosses the width, it should drop a line down.
It works only if you type SPACE after you crossed the width. I mean you can type `1000px` width of a line, but it goes down only if you type SPACE.

[JSbin demo](http://jsbin.com/zuwecica/1/edit)

**How can I fix it - when the user crosses the current width, a new line added?**

Thanks in advance

[Fixed Demo](http://jsbin.com/zuwecica/3/edit)
Thanks Artem Petrosian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `word-break` property to break the line without spaces:

```
word-break: break-all;
```